# Ability to accept multiple answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, voting, accepted-answer

Good day ladies and gentlemen,
I wonder how hard would it be to implement the possibility of accepting multiple answers, IT-wise. It arguably does happen that there is more than one good answer and there is no reasonable way to say that one is better than another.
Accepting just one (usually based on throwing an n-sided die) because system doesn't allow you otherwise, is a solution I'd call a hack, were I programming it :)

Of course, this question is not terribly important, so feel free to close. But I think it would make things go more smoothly on many occasions. It might also lower the number of requests for community wiki (which usually arise because someone yells "There is no correct answer here!!!").

> Is it worthwhile to try to implement the feature of being able to select multiple correct answers?

Relatedly, is there a discussion anywhere whether it would not make sense to alter voting/accepting system (in whatever way)? We are all familiar with 3pt answer being accepted and 100pt crawling somewhere under it (which is especially sad state of affairs when the 3pt answer is long). Or is everybody just so used to all these quirks you don't care anymore? :)

Comment: Accepted answer is an answer that worked **best** for the OP. Can there be multiple answers that worked best? Sure, if they're identical. But then you have to select just one of them.

Comment: Ultimately upvotes are for when you think multiple answers are good. Two non identical things being exactly equal is possible, but unlikely

Comment: The issue is not technical - it is about semantics. An accept has very specific meaning and allowing more than one accept changes what it means (not to mention that some people would end up accepting _all_ answers on a question, making the feature completely worthless).

Comment: Also re your related part; there is a discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot) regarding net downvoted answers loosing their "stuck to the top" privileges

Comment: This is a feature-request, so not a dupe of that linked question.

Comment: I am curious as to why all the downvotes?  I was going to ask this question myself, but you beat me to it!  I see this coming in handy where one user was able to answer one part of the question, while another user answered the other part of the question.

Comment: Just spotted this as a duplicate

Answer (score 12):

The purpose of an accepted answer is to show which answer worked the **best** for you; emphasis best. If there are many exceptional answers upvote them all but the chance of two being literally equal is highly unlikely. (or if that is insufficient (as oden says); award bounties for as many exceptional answers as you see fit).

The ability to mark multiple accepted answers would be ripe for misunderstanding; people would often accept all answers that were good, rather than the singular best one; diluting its meaning.

It would also give too much power to the question OP; allowing them to pin multiple answers to the top irrespective of community voting. At present the OP's preferred answer is directly followed by the communities preferred answer and this is a desirable state of affairs

Comment: Of course, one can offer and award a bounty for _each_ exceptional answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think this would be useful as an option that could be enabled per site, and then within that even perhaps per question by the asker. Not all Stack Exchange sites are about finding *solutions* that "work"; some are now more about exchanging information, and in that context it's much more likely that two different answers might be equally useful.