# Prioritize non-accepted answers with more than 10:1 votes of the accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, up-votes, unaccepted-answer

The SE model works well; OP asks and accepts, the community votes. You get two answers for the price of one; the one that works for OP and the one that works for the community.

*Let's face it: sometimes OP is wrong.*

I'm proposing that when a non-accepted answer's votes outweigh that of the accepted by at least 10:1*, the non-accepted answer is prioritized over the accepted one.

There are *tons* of examples across the network but for example, [this just came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235434/how-to-generate-a-random-long-salt-for-use-in-hashing).

<sub>* Good ratio? Open question, please discuss.</sub>

---

[inb4-dupe](/questions/tagged/inb4-dupe) This proposal isn't about "community accepted" answers per se, as suggested by [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature), but merely about prioritization in the UI.

Comment: In that case, as in most cases, the better answer is second -- which is probably high enough to be seen.  The accepted answer has a negative score; that alone is an indicator of problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree, but I disagree with the idea that the asker's opinion is more valuable in the ordering; the asker is posing the question to satisfy a deficit of knowledge, or for clarification. "This worked for me" doesn't necessarily mean "best answer".

Comment: Related; [Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot)

Comment: Also, in some circumstances it might be a ratio of 7:389 for accepted to top-voted. 7 isn't negative, but relatively speaking it might as well be.

Comment: [There are two major fallacies in your proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229379). You're promoting the cases where the current rules are bad, and neglecting the cases where they're good. Furthermore, you're omitting the downsides of your proposal (more complex rules). And you picked a bad example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235434/how-to-generate-a-random-long-salt-for-use-in-hashing/2235495#2235495 is not very good but not horribly bad — and since it has a negative score there's a clear indication that it may not be so good.

Comment: @Gilles I don't think it was a negative score when I posted it ;-) Regardless, I understand you point, good answer in the dupe link by the way.

Comment: @Gilles The suggested rule is (technically) simpler than the current one by allowing all answers to "float". I've found [some relevant statistics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189424/184077) on this as well; there's no real objective measure that defines a good or bad answer, but community votes should have an impact at some point imo.

Comment: @Jack These statistics are not useful to determine whether this change would improve things: they only says how many threads would be affected, but not whether they would be improved or worsened. The community votes do have an impact: the top-voted answer is guaranteed to be at most second from the top.