# Allow moderators to change the order of answers regardless of selected answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, moderators

Sometimes an answer that is accepted is incomplete or even wrong yet it masks the correct answer. This is an example

[JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

Would be nice for community moderators to be able to reorder the answer to make the correct one more visible.

Comment: there is a line written below explains everything "Anyone reading this, please scroll down and see ob's answer"

Comment: Moderators are not necessarily experts in *everything* a site covers. They should not be expected to be able to rank answers in terms of accuracy.

Comment: Users can flag it, the moderator does not need to be an expert to judge from the number of votes and comments that reordering the answers would be helpful.

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201634/allow-an-accepted-answer-to-become-unstuck-after-it-is-heavily-downvoted

Answer (score 6):

All the accepted answer means is that it's the answer than helped the questioner the most.

As a 3rd party you should be looking at what the community thinks is the best answer - which is the one that has the highest score. This appears directly below the accepted answer when the answers are sorted by votes (the default).